# Primes of the form $\frac{7^{q}+1}{7^m+1}$, where q is a positive integer and $m=q-n^2$

Tags: number-theory

$$\frac{7^{38}+1}{7^2+1}=2598696228942460402343442913969$$ is a 31 digit prime.

Are there other primes of the form

$$\frac{7^{q}+1}{7^{q-n^2}+1},$$ where $q$ and $n$ are positive integers?

Comment: @Peter $q=38$ and $n=6$ gives the prime $2598696228942460402343442913969$, are there other solutions?

Comment: For any such prime $p$, it will be the case that $p\mid 7^q+1$, so that's a handle to start looking with.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325934/primes-p-of-the-form-p-frac7q17q-n21 without notice to either site.

Comment: @Max Alekseyev why with necessity q-n^2 must be 2^k?

Comment: @homunculus: I've missed the power of $r$ there. I'm expanding my comment in an answer to avoid to clarify the points.

Answer (score 4):

Upto $q=10\ 000$ , the following primes of the desired form exist

$$\frac{7^{17}+1}{7^1+1}$$ $$\frac{7^{24}+1}{7^8+1}$$ $$\frac{7^{38}+1}{7^2+1}$$ $$\frac{7^{148}+1}{7^4+1}$$ with $14,14,31,122$ digits respective.

PARI/GP-code :

```
? for(q=1,1000,for(n=1,1000,m=q-n^2;if(m>0,s=(7^q+1)/(7^m+1);if(denominator(s)==
1,if(ispseudoprime(s)==1,print([m,q,n]))))))
[1, 17, 4]
[8, 24, 4]
[2, 38, 6]
[4, 148, 12]
```

For a larger limit, the following modified program should be used (for the sake of speed) :

```
? z=prod(j=1,3*10^4,prime(j));for(q=1,10^4,for(n=1,10^4,m=q-n^2;if(m>0,s=(7^q+1)
/(7^m+1);if(denominator(s)==1,if(gcd(s,z)==1,if(ispseudoprime(s)==1,print([m,q,n
])))))))
[1, 17, 4]
[8, 24, 4]
[2, 38, 6]
[4, 148, 12]
?
```

The $4$ primes found are proven primes.

Comment: for being prime do you Think that $q-n^2$ must be of the form 2^k where k is 0 or an integer Greater than 0?

Comment: @EnzoCreti This could be the case, but I have no proof yet. What is sure, that $$\frac{7^m+1}{7^n+1}$$ can only be a prime if $\ m=pn\ $ with odd prime $\ p$

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but an expanded comment.

First notice that $r:=q/(q-n^2)$ must be an odd prime, otherwise $p:=\frac{7^q+1}{7^{q-n^2}+1}$ cannot be prime.

If there exists an odd prime divisor $d\mid q$ such that $d\ne r$, then
$7^q+1$ is divisible by both $7^{q/r}+1$ and $7^{q/d}+1$. Since $\gcd(7^{q/r}+1,7^{q/d}+1)=7^{q/(dr)}+1$, we conclude that $\gcd(7^{q/r}+1,\frac{7^{q/d}+1}{7^{q/(dr)}+1})=1$ and thus $p=\frac{7^q+1}{7^{q/r}+1}$ has a non-trivial divisor $\frac{7^{q/d}+1}{7^{q/(dr)}+1}$. This contradicts the primality of $p$ and proves that such $d$ does not exist.

Hence, $q-n^2=2^k r^m$ for some $k\geq 0$ and $m\geq 0$. Then $q=2^kr^{m+1}$ and $n^2 = 2^kr^m(r-1)$, implying that $m$ is even, and $r$ is of the form $t^2+1$ or $2t^2+1$.